# Reading a multiple file input type destroy it

Tags: jquery, input

I am writing a jQuery script to upload several images at once but resizing them before uploading. Things work fine as for the resizing an uploading.

Nevertheless, I have trouble with 2 conflicting parts of the script.

First here is the html

```
         <form method="post" action="{{url('filemanager/manage')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
              <div class="input-group " >
                <label  id='fmg-multiple-input-label'>
                <input id='fmg-multiple-input' type="file" name="fmg-multiple-input[]" class="myfrm form-control " multiple="multiple">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-upload" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

and hereafter is the script

```
//FIST BLOCK
$('#fmg-multiple-input').change(function (e) {
    //write the selected file names in the label
    var files = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
        file = $(this)[0].files[i];
        files.push(file.name);
        //filemanager.resizeAndUpload(file);
    }
    $('#fmg-multiple-input-label').html(files.join(', '));
});

//SECOND BLOCK
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-upload', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fmg_upload_progress").show().empty();
        $('#fmg_file_form').fadeOut(10);
        //var input = $("#fmg-multiple-input").get(0);//a jQuery selector doesn't return a DOM element but a jQuery object
        var input = document.getElementById('fmg-multiple-input');//equivalent return the DOM element
        console.log(input);
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
            filemanager.resizeAndUpload(input.files[i]);
        }
    });
} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Please notice that all of this is inside a document ready wrap.

The first block of lines consists in writing the names of the files in the label.

Taken alone it works fine

The second block of lines calls a method for each files from the input field. This method resize the image and does an ajax request to upload it.

Taken alone this block works fine

The trouble arises when I try to use both. In the second block of lines, the

```
console.log(input)
```

returns an error saying the input is null.

It seems that the first block nullifies the input. Is there a mean to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `code` is that you are NOT closing the `label` before the input so when the `.html` method works for the first block it replace all the `HTML` of label and the next `siblings` it has since there is not close `label`

Hence why, the second block when it runs the input does `not` exist on that page at all because it been removed by `.html` method. Therefore you get `null` error in `console.log`

Also, Instead of using a `label` you should use `span` to display all the file `names` you have selected in input.

I have fixed up the `code` and it should work as intended.

**Live Working Example:**

```js
//FIST BLOCK
$('#fmg-multiple-input').change(function(e) {
  //write the selected file names in the label
  var files = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $(this)[0].files.length; i++) {
    file = $(this)[0].files[i];
    files.push(file.name);
    //filemanager.resizeAndUpload(file);
  }
  $('#fmg-multiple-input-label').html(files.join(', '));
});

//SECOND BLOCK
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-upload', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#fmg_upload_progress").show().empty();
    $('#fmg_file_form').fadeOut(10);
    //var input = $("#fmg-multiple-input").get(0);//a jQuery selector doesn't return a DOM element but a jQuery object
    var input = document.getElementById('fmg-multiple-input'); //equivalent return the DOM element
    console.log(input.files);
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      //filemanager.resizeAndUpload(input.files[i]);
    }
  });
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="{{url('filemanager/manage')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-group">
        <span id='fmg-multiple-input-label'></span><br>
        <input id='fmg-multiple-input' type="file" name="fmg-multiple-input[]" class="myfrm form-control " multiple="multiple">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-upload" style="margin-top:10px">Submit</button>
 </form>
```